# How do I make this Hlookup function work?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have been struggling with this problem for a couple of days, I do not see a problem with my function but it keeps showing N/A don't know why. I want to return population figures for each country in the second table starting from B7. Please help me understand my mistake. By the way, I am using the Russian version of Excel 2007 so in this case ЛОЖЬ=FALSE

[image]

Comment: Edit your post and reload the link for the Screen Shot since this one is non-viewable !!

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the search criteria (first argument) is equal to what you have in the list - also invisible / non printing characters "count", ...

... and if that doesn't help; verify that datatype settings are the same (select cell, hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> hit <kbd>1</kbd>) for the lookup array data and the cell with the first argument.